# How to manually control when the first week of the year begins?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to control when the first week of the year starts in Excel. The reason is that my work has Week 1 starting on January 2 for 2022.

How can I modify this formula or create a new one that will do this?

`=WEEKNUM("1-Jan-2022")`

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the weeks start on a Sunday, it is just that we have a Week 53 trailing into the new year by a day. Wouldn't starting all the dates on a Monday throw off all the weeks?

Comment: Looks like a bug, errr, I mean feature.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want the first week of the year to be shorter than 7 days or are you trying to say that the first week of the year must start on the first Sunday of the year and that each week is 7 days (including the first week)?

Comment: @FlexYourData Our first week of the year begins Jan 2nd. It lies on a Sunday and all the rest remains the same. January 2-8 should show Week 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=WEEKNUM(A1)-IF(WEEKDAY(YEAR(A1))=1,0,1)

=WEEKNUM(TODAY())-IF(WEEKDAY(YEAR(TODAY()))=1,0,1)
```

Assumes A1 is a valid date.  TODAY() can be substituted for A1

WEEKNUM returns 1 to 54 corresponding to start of year and Sunday (or other days with modifiers).

No problem if year starts on Sunday, otherwise when Sunday rolls around week count is off by 1.

If Jan 1 of present year is not a Sunday, subtract 1 from week count.

This formula makes the first days of the year as week 0.

```
=WEEKNUM(A1)-AND(IF(WEEKDAY(YEAR(A1))=1,0,1),WEEKNUM(A1)<>1)
```

We take advantage of AND and data is 1 (boolean) to mask out (AND) correction for first days of year.  Week should go from 1 to 52 (53?).  First Sunday in year will be Week 1 and previous days will be week 1.  Week 1 could be 13 days long!

Comment: What I am wanting to do here is just list the current week that we are in. I won't have dates listed everywhere. I would probably have a single field pointing to today's date. How could this be molded to accomplish that?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
=ROUNDUP((DAYS(A2,DATE(2022,1,2))+1)/7,0)
```

where the date you want to return the week number for is in cell A2.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without having a reference sheet for all dates in the year?

Comment: You don't need a reference sheet. As I understood your question, you wanted a function or a formula that would return the weeknum when week 1 starts on 2022-01-02. This formula does that. Any date that you want to calculate the week number for, you can just put that date where it says A2, or refer to any other cell containing a date.

Comment: What I am wanting to do here is just list the current week that we are in. I won't have dates listed everywhere. I would probably have a single field pointing to today's date.

Comment: OK, just replace A2 with TODAY()

Comment: @user1530279 I think the way this answer was presented was just to show you that the formula returns your desired result for a range of possible inputs, it is not using that list of dates.

Answer (score 0):

`=WEEKNUM(Date;Mode)`

Excel or LibreOffice

Hit <kbd>F1</kbd> then type "WEEKNUM" into the search field and have it all revealed.

`Mode` sets what is to be considered to be the first day of week 1 in any year.

Ref: [LibreOffice 7.2 Help on WEEKNUM](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/scalc/01/func_weeknum.html)